# Exclude Workspace’ filesystem folders from search in Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

When using [Workspaces](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/setup/setup-workflow) in Chromes’ Developer Tools performing a [search](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/setup/setup-workflow#search_for_files_or_text) will include local folders added to the workspace:

> To search for a loaded file in DevTools, press `Ctrl + O` or `Cmd + O` (Mac) to open a search dialog. You can still do this in Workspaces, but the search is expanded to both the remote loaded files and the local files in your Workspace folder.

This slows down the search measurably because Chrome indexes local files. On bigger projects with many files (`node_modules` etc.) it takes sereral minutes to load the search results.

Is there a way to only search the remote loaded files i. e. exclude local folders?

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
/node_modules/|/bower_components/|/\.devtools|/\.git/|/\.sass-cache/|/\.hg/|/\.idea/|/\.svn/|/\.cache/|/\.project/|/\.DS_Store$|/\.Trashes$|/\.Spotlight-V100$|/\.AppleDouble$|/\.LSOverride$|/Icon$|/\._.*$
```

as your exclude pattern.